# как мне вывести на сервер структуру папок в JSON

Tags: php, json, файловая-система, response

такой код выводит массив с директориями которые находятся в папке *dir*

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');



$data = scandir('../dir/');
echo json_encode($data);
```

дерево папок на сервере примерно такое

```
dir/one/oneChild
dir/two/twoChild
dir/three/threeChild
```

хотелось бы получит что то типа этого в формате JSON , то-есть всю структуру папок из папки *dir*

```
[
  {
    "one": {
      "oneChild": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "two": {
      "twoChild": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "three": {
      "threeChild": {}
    }
  }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например можно рекурсивно таким образом.

```
function getDirTree($path)
{
  $result = [];
  $files = scandir($path);

  foreach ($files as $file) {

    if(! in_array($file, ['.','..'])) {

      if(is_dir($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) {
        $result[$file] = getDirTree($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
      } else {
        $result[] = $file;
      }
    }

  }
  return $result;
}

$data = getDirTree('my-dir');

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: можно ли как то регулировать вложенность если мне нужно максимум 3 уровня в глубину ? и как исключить папки типа .idea